# Getting a substring using method does not work

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to introduce a method in my program which should result into a substring. I wrote the following code but why would not this work?

```
class testmethod {

   String FQDN = "TEST.domain.local"
   def sname = shortname(FQDN);
   println $sname

     def shortname(Longname)
        {
          shortname1 =  Longname.substring(0, Longname.indexOf('.'))
          return shortname1
        }
     }
```

Comment: is it part of real code? or just a "pseudocode"? it doesn't look like something real, hard to answer in such form, too many syntax errors here

Comment: Interesting code style convention indeed http://www.myfacewhen.net/uploads/2058-thinking.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code should be(for better readability) :-

`def shortname(String Longname)` not `def shortname(Longname)`.

Also `shortname1 =  Longname.substring(0, Longname.indexOf('.'))` in this `shortname1` is not defined.

Moreover you can try :-

```
def shortname(String Longname)
        {
          String[] shortnameArr =  Longname.split("\\.");
          return shortnameArr[0];// will return TEST
        }
```

Comment: I am saying `String Longname`, not the `def sname` or `def shortname`

Comment: @AnkitNigam `def shortname(Longname)` is equal to `def shortname(def Longname)`. It's nice to define actual class as `String` instead of default `def`, some people who will read this code in future will appreciate that, but it's not what @rora asked

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, thanx for clarifying. BTW just offtopic, but i used your FB SpringSecurity. Very Well done.

Comment: @AnkitNigam thanks for using it :) btw, updated answer looks good, I guess original issue was because of undefined `shortname1`, but code in the question is real mess, hard to say what @rora meant

Comment: Sorry Guys. just started with Groovy. coming from perl/vbscript background and have no experience with JAVA.
@IgorArtamonov - you are right. This is not the complete code. currently i have started working on to migrate a VBScript code to Groovy and in this script i have function where a FQDN is changed to hostname by using such function.

the bad thing in groovy is that there are many way to do the same thing.

btw the error i am getting is (Groovy console) is 

1 compilation error:

unexpected token: println at line: 5, column: 4

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing both script and class concepts of the Groovy in one single piece of code.

Just remove the class definition and $ sign to use the script way:

```
   String FQDN = "TEST.domain.local"
   def sname = shortname(FQDN);
   println sname

     def shortname(Longname)
        {
          shortname1 =  Longname.substring(0, Longname.indexOf('.'))
          return shortname1
        }
```

Or add class initialization and local variable declaration to use the class way:

```
class testmethod {
   String FQDN = "TEST.domain.local"
   def sname = shortname(FQDN);

     def shortname(Longname)
        {
          def shortname1 =  Longname.substring(0, Longname.indexOf('.'))
          return shortname1
        }
}

def tc = new testmethod()
println tc.sname
```